Output Curl and Grep to a variable

I need to run a curl command
Grep that HTML curl output to search for a particular string
If the grep string is present in the curl output, return true. Else False.

Something like follows:
output=$(curl -s "https://www.example.com | grep -o "This"")
echo "$output"

if [ $output = 1 ]
then
  echo "Success"
else
  echo "Fail";
fi

Just that output variable does not have anything when I try to echo
What am I missing?

curl -s "https://www.example.com | grep -o "This"" should be curl -s "https://www.example.com" | grep -o "This" (quote moved to enclose just the url). Also, after filtering the output for lines that include This, they will never equal just 1. Maybe you wanted to check the value of the exit status $?

perfect! Thank you so much. How would I output 1 or zero instead of the matched string? Right now it returns "This" since that is the matching variable @pmf

It depends on which process you want it from, curl or grep (both can fail). Also note that generally an exit code of 0 means success (not the other way round as your code suggests).

@pmf I want to check the exit status code as well. If the string is present in the output, return success, else failure. So, exit 0 if there is a match and exit 1 if there is no match

Please Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex. I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Can you show the HTML you need to match? I will give you a better way

So, curl -s "https://www.example.com" gives a HTML output, i want to match "This domain" and see if the string is present in the html output @Gilles

Your question is a bit vague. Please add a small sample of your HTML (no need complete one)

Please, read How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example.

grep -o "This" outputs either This or nothing. If you want the exit status, look at the value of $? immediately after the pipeline completes. (You can use grep -qo "This" since you don't appear to actually care about the output, and can like use grep -q This for the same reason.)

Thank you @chepner. What if I actually care about the output? Lets say if the output of the grep is "abc" I want  to do action 1, if output of the grep is "xyz" I want to do action 2, else action 3. Basically match the output using if/else.

You can still capture the output, but that output is not the exit status, which is stored in $? until the next command you execute.

Perfect. thank you

I’m voting to close this question because the poster didn't use http://shellcheck.net as directed by the [tag:bash] tag.

With bash:
output=$(curl -s "https://www.example.com" | grep -o "This")
if [[ $? == 0 ]]; then
  echo "Success"
else
  echo "Fail"
fi

Btw.: I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

What I would do if This is not in code but text, with a proper XML/HTML parser:
xidel -e '//*[contains(., "This")]' 'https://www.example.com'

This use a XPath query.
See:
https://github.com/benibela/xidel
https://sourceforge.net/projects/videlibri/files/Xidel/

Another solution for text based search (no need a variable at all):
if curl 'https://www.example.com' | html2text | grep -q 'This'; then
    echo 'match'
else
    echo 'no match'
fi


One might also like: https://github.com/bjesus/pipet : in this case curl https://www.example.com .This

Looks interesting, but I don't see XPath support

The bash script you provided currently makes the use of grep with curl correctly piped incorrect.
What you can try to check if the grep found a match from the output of curl.
#!/bin/bash

output=$(curl -s "https://www.example.com" | grep -o "This")

if [ -n "$output" ]; then
  echo "Success"
else
  echo "Fail"
fi


It's not really clear what you mean by "return true, else return false".  In the shell, the default behavior for a function is to return the exit status of the last command that was run.  Also, grep has the nice property of returning a "success" status (zero) if it matches the pattern, and a "failure" status (non-zero) if it does not match the pattern.  So your function can be as simple as:
check_curl() { curl ... | grep ... ; }

Maybe you want to paramterize the url and the pattern and write:
check_curl() { curl "$1" | grep "$2; }

Certainly if [ "$output" = 1 ] is not what you want to do, as that is checking if the string that matched was the literal string 1.  Perhaps you were thinking if [ $? = 0 ], but that is much better written as:
if curl ... | grep ...; then echo success; else echo failure >&2; fi

In that, the output of grep will precede the printing of "success", so you probably want to add -q to the invocation of grep (or redirect to the bit bucket).
